# Get CultureInfo object from country name or RegionInfo object

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture, region

Given a specific country code, e.g. "CH", how can I get a CultureInfo object? The specific country code is dynamic (changes at runtime).
I only have the country code, and i want to know if it is possible to create a CultureInfo object from **just** the country code. It doesn't matter which exact culture I get (fr-CH/de-CH).

I'm trying do something like this:

```
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("CH");
```

Would it be possible  to create a culture from a RegionInfo object?
Then it would look like this:

```
RegionInfo r= new RegionInfo("CH");
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(r);
```

Obviously the preceding examples don't compile, they just give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What culture do you expect to get for Canada or Belgium?

Comment: Are you looking for [CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yck8b540.aspx)?

Comment: For ***US*** you get `chr-US en-US es-US and haw-US` : _Cheroqui, English, Spanish, Hawai_

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you only have the country code, you could use something like this to get all culture infos associated with that country:

```
var cultureInfos = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                              .Where(c => c.Name.EndsWith("-CH"));
```

EDIT: adding `-` before `CH` to prevent an edge case, as pointed out by @JeppeStigNielsen (see comments below).

Comment: useful **`iso2 = "US";`** Code:`var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Where(c => c.Name.EndsWith(iso2)).ToList();
            foreach (System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture in cultureList)
            {
                Response.Write("<br /> Culture for " + iso2 + ": " + culture.DisplayName 
                    + " *** " + culture.NativeName
                    + " " + culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName + " - " + culture.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName
                    + " - " + culture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern);
            }`

Comment: This question kind-of deserves an ugly answer (and I just posted another one), but still: When I try your code with __Haiti__, country code `"HT"`, one of the cultures I get back is `"zh-CHT"`, __Chinese (Traditional) Legacy__, known natively as __中文(繁體) 舊版__.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Changing the code above to `EndsWith("-CH")` would to the trick or you can think of another edge case?

Comment: I do not think there will be any examples if you do that. Even if some neutral cultures contain a hyphen, for example `"sr-Cyrl"`, __Serbian (Cyrillic)__ (no country specified), or `"mn-Mong"`, __Mongolian (Traditional Mongolian)__ (no country specified), where the second part specifies the writing system because the language can be written with different scripts, the second part will have _more_ than two letters in that case.

Comment: This is incredibly fragile. Do not rely on string existence checks, you'll break somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Are you trying to create a CultureInfo object ? like this:

```
CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("de-CH"); //culture for  German (Switzerland)
CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("fr-CH"); //culure for French (Switzerland)
CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("it-CH"); //culture for Italian (Switzerland)
```

Maybe this link can be useful http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/ it show all Cultures.

Comment: I only have the country code, and I want to know if it is possible to create a CultureInfo object from just the country code. But it must be dynamic.

Comment: Can I get `CultureInfo` using **HKCU\Control Panel\International\Geo** - ***Nation*** value ?

Answer (score 6):

Of course this is an ugly thing to do because a country (including your example `"CH"` Switzerland) can have many languages.

Still, I will offer you two ugly methods. First one:

```
static IEnumerable<CultureInfo> FindCandidateCultures(RegionInfo region)
{
  return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
    .Where(x => (new RegionInfo(x.Name)).GeoId == region.GeoId);
}
```

When used on your particular example, `new RegionInfo("CH")`, it gives, on my version of the .NET Framework and my Windows version:

```
de-CH: German (Switzerland)
fr-CH: French (Switzerland)
gsw-CH: Alsatian (Switzerland)
it-CH: Italian (Switzerland)
rm-CH: Romansh (Switzerland)
wae-CH: Walser (Switzerland)
```

*Edit:* A later version gives the above, plus these two:

```
en-CH: English (Switzerland)
pt-CH: Portuguese (Switzerland)
```

The second method I will offer you:

```
// ugly reflection, this can break any day!
static CultureInfo ConvertToCulture(RegionInfo region)
{
  var data = typeof(RegionInfo).GetField("m_cultureData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(region);

  var name = (string)(data.GetType().GetProperty("SNAME", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(data));

  return CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(name);
}
```

As is evident, it uses internal representations of `mscorlib.dll`, and we never know if it will break with future versions. But it does give you a way to pick a particular culture. On my machine, from `new RegionInfo("CH")`, you get `it-CH: Italian (Switzerland)`.

*Edit:* Unsurprisingly, the second method has changed in some versions of .NET. Something like:

```
var data = typeof(RegionInfo).GetField("_cultureData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(region);

var name = (string)(data.GetType().GetProperty("CultureName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(data));
```

or (if you use nullable reference types) with a lot of `!`:

```
var data = typeof(RegionInfo).GetField("_cultureData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    !.GetValue(region);

var name = (string)(data!.GetType().GetProperty("CultureName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    !.GetValue(data)!);
```