# Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name US is an invalid culture identifier

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, culture

I tried to use a ISO-3166 two letter country code to create my C# culture info object to format my `datetime` objects according to the locale.

If I try:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("FR");
```

it works fine, if I try:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("US");
```

it throws an exception:

> Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name US is an invalid
>   culture identifier.

The funny thing is that "US" is a valid ISO-3166 country code.

Comment: Check [full list of cultures](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/)

Comment: What is your actual question? How to fix it?  How to map from country codes to cultures? ...?

Comment: yes. I'd like to know how to map ISO-3166 country codes to C# cultures

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini There is no such a built-in mapping. You need to create yourself.

Comment: [Potential dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926400/get-cultureinfo-object-from-country-name-or-regioninfo-object)?

Comment: fr means french, not france
en mean english
en-gb means english great britain
en-au means english australia
en-us means english united states
there is no language or culture named 'us'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [`CultureInfo(string)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky2chs3h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation;

> For a list of predefined culture names, see the [National Language
>   Support (NLS) API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx)

Also from [`CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.twoletterisolanguagename.aspx)

> For example, the two-letter abbreviation for English is `en`.

There is no `US` defined but there is `en` (if you *really* have to use two letter name) which you can use it. All of them defined in [ISO 639-1 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1).

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en");
```

Comment: ok. so basically the CultureInfo constructor doesn't accept directly ISO-3166 country codes...

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini It _can_ accept some of them but **not** all. Those are different standards.

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Yes. You can create your own `KeyValuePair<string, string>` for example.

Comment: Ok thanks. Answer accepted. Any advice on where to find such mapping? I mean, can't believe I'm the first one to face such problem....

Answer (score 1):

Argument of `CultureInfo` constructor is not a ISO-3166 code, but predefined culture name

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky2chs3h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article concerning `CultureInfo`:

> For a list of predefined culture names, see the National Language
>   Support (NLS) API [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) at the Go Global Developer Center.

In the reference mentioned there is no `us` culture, but there is `en-US`, so you have to use ut.

Answer (score 1):

Because `US` is not a valid culture name whereas FR is. CultureInfo's constructor doesn't accepts country code as parameter. It expects the "Culture Name".

Refer the table in this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(vs.71).aspx) for valid culture names.